# NHibernate: [PropertyAccessException: Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches)

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

This is the error that I've been getting when I try to run this code:

```
Icriteria critBKCP = sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(BklCustomerProduct));

IList<BklCustomerProduct> objBklCustomerProducts = critBKCP.List<BklCustomerProduct>();
```

Debugging I found that this exception was thrown here (in the set part):

```
public virtual DateTime? Datemodif
{
    get { return m_datemodif; }
    set
    {
        m_datemodif = value.Value;
    }
}
```

My mapping for that part is the following:

```
 <property column="datemodif" type="DateTime" name="Datemodif" />
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your mapping:

```
<property column="datemodif" type="System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib]], mscorlib" name="Datemodif" />
```

Comment: so the problem isn't in this property

Comment: Any hint to where should I look?

Comment: In the inner exception will probably show what property is wrong mapped

Comment: That's where I first looked, but the InnerException is just {specified cast is not valid} and null.

Comment: nowhere says what class is generating this error when mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining that the type is  a datetime in Your mapping. However, the type is a nullable datetime. Omit the type specification in Your mapping Definition. Nhibernate can find It out himself.

Comment: The modified line now looks like this: `<property column="datemodif" name="Datemodif" />`. And still throws the same error.